# How do I query in Google Datastore Viewer where table or column name has slash in it?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

In Google Datastore, I have a table (Kind) with a slash in its name.

In the old [Datastore Viewer](http://appengine.google.com/datastore/) GUI, I can run

```
select * from "foo/bar"
```

with doublequotes. So, *foo/bar* **is** a valid table name.

But in the new GUI, [Datastore Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/), I have no way of doing this.

I get

```
GQL query error: Encountered ""foo/bar"" at line 1, column 15. 
Was expecting one of: <UNQUOTED_NAME>, <QUOTED_NAME>
```

See screenshot  [image: Error message]

How can I query this table? (Backslash-escaping also doesn't work.)

(My question also is about columns, where the same problems occur.)

When the old GUI  is shut down, I will be almost completely unable to access my data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use  backquote.

```
select * from `foo/bar`
```

Please note it is `  not '